# Unable to get JsonConverterFactory working in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, system.text.json

I've gone down a really frustrating rabbit trail with my conversion from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json in .NET 7 (console application).

I have several DTOs that contain properties of type `IReadOnlyCollection<MyObject>` where I have a `JsonConverter` for `MyObject` to handle some backward-compatibility conversion logic (like converting a raw `string` to `MyObject`).

During my journey, I learned that System.Text.Json is unable to process elements of collections using a `JsonConverter` for the element type. Instead, those `JsonConverter.CanProcess()` calls receive the collection type, not the type of its elements. Newtonsoft provided this out of the box as I never really struggled to get it to use the converter for single items (properties of type `MyObject`) or collections of items (properties of type `IReadOnlyCollection<MyObject>`).

I'll post some code below that I'm trying. The behavior I see today is that my `JsonConverterFactory.CreateConverter()` is called (good). The new `ReadOnlyCollectionJsonConverter` is returned, but its `CanConvert` is never called (bad).

My expectation is that my `ReadOnlyCollectionJsonConverter` will be called and then piggy-back on `TermDataConverter` to convert the elements (since both of these converters ultimately get stuffed into System.Text.Json via the `Converters` property of my `JsonSerializerOptions`)

### The Factory

```cs
public class CollectionJsonConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return !IsExcludedType(typeToConvert) &&
            typeToConvert.IsGenericType &&
            IsAssignableToGenericType(typeToConvert, typeof(IEnumerable<>));
    }

    private static bool IsExcludedType(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsPrimitive ||
            type == typeof(string);
    }

    private static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(Type givenType, Type genericType)
    {
        var interfaceTypes = givenType.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
            .Select(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition());

        return interfaceTypes.Contains(genericType);
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var elementType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var converterType = typeof(ReadOnlyCollectionJsonConverter<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(converterType);

        if (instance is null)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        return (JsonConverter) instance;
    }
}
```

### The Collection JsonConverter

```cs
public sealed class ReadOnlyCollectionJsonConverter<TElement> : JsonConverter<IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert.IsGenericType &&
            typeToConvert == typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<>) &&
            typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(TElement);
    }

    public override IReadOnlyCollection<TElement> Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        var list = new List<TElement>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
            {
                break;
            }

            var elementValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TElement>(ref reader, options);
            if (elementValue is not null)
            {
                list.Add(elementValue);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        IReadOnlyCollection<TElement> value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        foreach (var element in value)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, element, options);
        }
    }
}
```

### The TermData JsonConverter

```cs
public class TermDataConverter : JsonConverter<TermData>
{
    public override TermData? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType is JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            var str = reader.GetString();
            return str is not null ? new TermData {Term = str} : null;
        }

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TermData>(ref reader, options);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TermData value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }
}
```

### JsonSerializerOptions Setup

```cs
_jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions(GlobalJsonSerializerSettings.Services)
{
    Converters =
    {
        new CollectionJsonConverter(),
        new TermDataConverter()
    }
};
```

### DTOs

```cs
public record TermData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("trash_id")]
    public string TrashId { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    public string Term { get; init; } = string.Empty;
}

public record PreferredTermData
{
    public int Score { get; init; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<TermData> Terms { get; init; } = Array.Empty<TermData>();
}

public record ReleaseProfileData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("trash_id")]
    public string TrashId { get; init; } = string.Empty;

    public string Name { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    public bool IncludePreferredWhenRenaming { get; init; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<TermData> Required { get; init; } = Array.Empty<TermData>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<TermData> Ignored { get; init; } = Array.Empty<TermData>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<PreferredTermData> Preferred { get; init; } = Array.Empty<PreferredTermData>();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, first of all the `ReadOnlyCollectionJsonConverter` does not write start and end array, fix that:

```
public sealed class ReadOnlyCollectionJsonConverter<TElement> : JsonConverter<IReadOnlyCollection<TElement>>
{
    public override IReadOnlyCollection<TElement> Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        IReadOnlyCollection<TElement> value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var element in value)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, element, options);
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Also you can remove the `CanConvert` override (it is kind of useless and wrong because `typeToConvert == typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<>)` should always be false).

And in `TermDataConverter` you need to create a copy of options without itself to prevent endless cycle:

```
public class TermDataConverter : JsonConverter<TermData>
{
    public override TermData? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType is JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            var str = reader.GetString();
            return str is not null ? new TermData {Term = str} : null;
        }
        var jsonSerializerOptions = CopyOptsWithoutSelf(options);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TermData>(ref reader, jsonSerializerOptions);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TermData value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonSerializerOptions = CopyOptsWithoutSelf(options);
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, jsonSerializerOptions);
    }

    private static JsonSerializerOptions CopyOptsWithoutSelf(JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        var jsonConverter = jsonSerializerOptions.Converters
            .FirstOrDefault(converter => converter.GetType() == typeof(TermDataConverter));
        if (jsonConverter is not null)
        {
            jsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Remove(jsonConverter);
        }
        return jsonSerializerOptions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestions. But this does not fix the original root issue. You've found a lot of issues I overlooked because I haven't been able to get code to execute that far. I still get no calls to `TermDataConverter.Read()` or even `ReadOnlyCollectionJsonConverter.Read()` when I attempt to deserialize.

Comment: @void.pointer works fine for me - corresponding `Read` methods are called on deserialization.

Comment: @void.pointer - [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GXJw9S)

Comment: @void.pointer also `IsAssignableToGenericType(typeToConvert, typeof(IEnumerable<>))` is actually wrong too. You need to match current type not  it's interfaces.

Comment: I apologize, I had the incorrect naming set in one of my unit tests which explains why none of this code was being hit, because the property names were the wrong convention in the JSON data. With your changes, everything is working great. Thank you for walking through this with me!

Comment: One last reply regarding your last comment about the comparison to `IEnumerable`. The goal later is to support more collection types than just `IReadOnlyCollection`. I left my code a little bit incomplete. I would have some kind of switch statement in the `CreateConverter()` method to hopefully reuse some of this code for collection types with a common base and common parsing semantics.